# Can't change timezone with created username despite being part of the Administrators group in Windows Server 2022

Tags: windows-server-2022

On Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, when I login under a username/account I created and I try to change the Timezone through settings, it is greyed out and I cannot change it, despite the user being part of the "Administrators" group.

I can however change the timezone through the timedate.cpl control panel with the created username/account.

If I login as "Administrator" I can in fact change the time zone through settings.

Is there another way I need to configure my custom user account so it has "all" the privileges of the "Administrator" account? I'm  concerned there may be other restrictions on my custom account that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Do you have a Domain Controller running or is it pure local users?

Comment: The Timezone is afaik Serverwide setting, this is not a user only one as i know

Comment: This is a pure local user for now. No domains are involved (yet)

Comment: This seems to be a "known" issue. My suggestion would be to continue using the method you're currently using (which is what I do) or use Server Manager to change the timezone.